# How to uncheck the header checkbox in WebDataGrid in C#

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, webdatagrid

I have a WebDataGrid and an UnboundCheckBoxField column. I want to be able to check and uncheck the check box in the header from the code behind, thereby selecting or unselecting all the items.
There is WebDataGrid1.Columns["IsActive"].Header but there is no value there I can set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, just cast the column to `UnboundCheckBoxField` and use `HeaderChecked` property.

**Code snippet (C#):**

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UnboundCheckBoxField checkboxField = (WebDataGrid1.Columns[0] as UnboundCheckBoxField);

    checkboxField.HeaderChecked = !checkboxField.HeaderChecked;
}
```

**Code snippet (aspx):**

```
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid1" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="400px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
    <ig:UnboundCheckBoxField Key="Check" HeaderChecked="true" Width="25px" />
    ...
</Columns>
<Behaviors>
    <ig:EditingCore>
        <Behaviors>
            <ig:CellEditing>
            </ig:CellEditing>
        </Behaviors>
    </ig:EditingCore>
</Behaviors>
```

**Gif:**

[image]